# Is "Dank Farrik" an exclamatory or a cuss word?

Tags: star-wars, languages, terminology

I have seen Dank Farrik being used only in the Mandalorian show and only in scenes where the word sayer either is in trouble or just surprised.

This makes me wonder is it an exclamatory word akin to - "God Damn" or "Shit!" or is it more of a cuss word like - "Fuck" or "What the fuck" ?

Comment: Can you explain what you think the difference is between the two options?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's definitely a curse.

> “*Dank farrik,*” **the other woman cursed softly** under her breath.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Mandalorian Season 2 Junior Novel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Mandalorian_Season_2_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

and

> “*Dank farrik!*” **Fennec cursed**, and they ran out of the building in time
> to see the majordomo whipping around the corner in a landspeeder.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Book of Boba Fett Junior Novel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Book_of_Boba_Fett_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

and

> “*Dank farrik*” is **the curse of choice for the rougher side of the
> galaxy far, far away.** Cara Dune, the Mythrol, and the Mandalorian have
> all uttered it at least once.
>
> <sub><sup>[StarWars.com - We Have Spoken: 40 of the Best Quotes from The Mandalorian](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-mandalorian-quotes)</sup></sub>

---

Quite what it *means* is anyone's guess.

Comment: Well, we know what *dank* means so...

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Probably it's intended as a replacement swear word for "damn and f*ck"

Comment: It might also be a proper noun, used in vain - a group called the [Dank Graks](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dank_Graks) was recently established to have existed in the High Republic era, for example.

Comment: @MiloP - Rodians suffered from the danks also; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rodian_Dank

Comment: As a side note - how exactly does a junior novel of a TV series work... I get a novel of a book, but is it a chapter an episode or something?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Yep. One chapter per episode. And it follows the on-screen almost perfectly

Answer (score -3):

I interpreted the second word as *ferric* i.e. made of or concerning iron, and my headcanon is that the literal meaning is being able to smell rust; implying either:

- this place/ship is a s***hole *
- that moisture has got into the guts of your ship and has started corroding it. **

It certainly sounds more like *ferric* to me; novel writers aren't always fully appraised of all the lore of a screen production, so I'd think the only authoritative source as to spelling is the script. Is this what they meant? Unanswerable with the information I've been able to find.

* *Given Mandalorians' religious reverence for equipment maintenance, this is an especially scornful notion for them*

** *This is substantially worse news than it would be in a land or seagoing vehicle because 1) you have a leak from something **inside** the ship and 2) it'll keep getting worse until your hull breaches.*

Comment: I'm reasonably certain it's supposed to be a bowdlerised version of fuck

Comment: @Valorum 'Fuck' _means_ to fornicate and has no integral meaning as an exclamation or curse without context. You aren't contradicting my answer, since it's _obvious_ that it's a curse or expletive.

Comment: The show's subtitles all say "farrik". It's fun as headcanon though.

Comment: Creative answer, but aren't we supposed to avoid pure speculation? This answer could be improved if there were textual or on-screen support.